# Replicating shiny tmap with leaflet?

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, tmap

I've built the following app https://iseak.shinyapps.io/Mapa/
and I would like to switch from tmap to leaflet for the map portion of the app because I've run into some limitations (I'd like fancier popups and some other stuff).

Currently the map is working with tmap using the following code:

```
output$map = renderLeaflet({
  
  tm <- tm_shape(subsetData()) +
    tm_fill(selvar(), palette=colores(),
            alpha=0.95,
            breaks=breaks(),
            id="Zona", 
            popup.vars=c(" "="popover"),
            popup.format=list(digits=2),  
            legend.show = F,
            labels=c(" "=selvar())
            
    ) + 
    tm_borders() +
    tmap_options(basemaps = "CartoDB.Positron"
    ) 
  
  
  tmap_leaflet(tm) %>%
    removeLayersControl()
})
```

My starting point when trying to use leaflet directly is:

```
output$map = renderLeaflet({
  
  leaflet(data=subsetData()) %>%
    addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>% 
    clearShapes() %>% 
    clearControls() %>% 
    addPolygons(data = subsetData(),
                fillColor = ~colores()(selvar()),
                fillOpacity = 0.9,
                weight = 2)
  
  
})
```

But I keep getting errors. I would appreciate some pointers on how to easily switch from tmap to leaflet and how to use reactive values inside the leaflet call. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite open. I think the leaflet website has quite good example code (https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/). Browse through the left menu.

When it come to reactivity you don't need brackets to use variable created by `reactiveValues`; in case of `reactive()` you need some.

Looking at your code I'm not sure what is behind color() and selvar(). Assuming selvar() is the number for the color scale my approach would have been something like this:

```
selvar <- reactiveValues(n=c(1:10)

output$map = renderLeaflet({
    pal <- leaflet::colorBin(brewer.pal(9,"Blues"), domain = selvar, bins = 7, na.color = "gray")

    leaflet() %>%
        addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>%
        addPolygons(data=shp,
                    fillColor = ~pal(selvar),
                    fillOpacity = 0.9,
                    weight = 2)
```

You can specify your shape data in `leaflet()` or in `addPolygons()`. Using the latter allows to use different shape file tables. Finally, another useful pointer is `leafletProxy('map')` which would work well with the year buttons underneath the map for fast updates.

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look at it. Regarding leafletProxy: what I'm currently doing is subsetting the data based on all the inputs (including the year buttons) prior to running leaflet(), so that selvar() only includes the values for the selected year. Would you recommend switching to leafletProxy for this, should that update the map faster? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, that I through in the leafletProxy function in the mix w/o the idea (which was not 100% on point). The idea of `leafletProxy` is to modify an existing map rather than redrawing it and thereby saving the time of generating the entire map again. Therefore you need to draw the map with `leaflet`. But your time-buttons could re-access the map via `leafletProxy`, strip polygons (`clearShapes()`) and add an updated polygon layer back: observe({ leafletProxy('map') %>% clearShapes() %>% clearControls() %>% addPolygons(...) })